# Angular 10 - Trying to Enable/Disable a Save button based on if a new entity is being added or one is being edited

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a set of input fields, two out of five which are required. I have a SAVE and CANCEL button. A user can either create a new entity, or edit an existing one. The CANCEL button is always active. But for the SAVE button, I don't want it active for a *new* entity until the required fields are entered. If the are entered and then removed, the SAVE button goes inactive again. All of this works fine.

But when editing an existing entity, I can't get the logic right. When you start editing, the SAVE button is always inactive. You have to remove one of the fields and then reenter it to make it active.

HTML:

```
<bi-action-save [disabled]="(disableSaveBtn$ | async)" (execute)="saveTrigger$.next()"></bi-action-save>
```

Typescript:

```
disable$ = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(); 

disableSaveBtn$ = combineLatest([this.disabled$.pipe(startWith(false))
, this.disable$.pipe(startWith(false))
, this.formValid$.pipe(map(x => !x), startWith(false))
, this.$hasPendingChanges.pipe(map(x => !x), startWith(false))
, this.isSaving$.pipe(startWith(false))])
.pipe(map(([a, b, c, d, e]) => a || b || c || d || e));
```

Important: Please take it for granted that $hasPendingChanges is working correctly.

I'm thinking maybe I need a boolean or something to set based on when an entity (which is an $Input() is being edited and add it to the HTML save button, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you confirm this combineLatest  fires when you click edit ?